# Shannon sampling for $L^1(\mathbb R)$ functions

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, signal-processing

Suppose that $f \in L^p(\mathbb R), 1 \leq p \leq 2$ is such that the Fourier transform of $f$ has support in the interval $[0,1]$. If $p=2$ then by Shannon's sampling Theorem we have the for every $a \in (0,1]$ the implication
$$
f(an) = 0 \ \ \forall n \in \mathbb Z \implies f =0.
$$
Does this implication holds also holds for $p=1$ and every $a \in (0,1]$?

Comment: Well $\hat{f}$ is continuous and compactly supported whence $L^2$ so that $f$ is $L^2$ as well